# TypeError: image.elevateZoom is not a function: Failure in Magento 1.9 RWD theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento

In Magento 1.9 CE, if we browse the product reviews page, it displays an error

> TypeError: image.elevateZoom is not a function

This is because, magento is zooming image in product page using this [plugin](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples)

the JavaScript interpreter, because of a failure shuts down on this page, JavaScript is not executed. This leads to decreased functionality of the page.

Can anyone help me on how to remove this error so that I can use js on this page?

[These](http://magento-forum.ru/topic/4430/) guys say they have solved the problem, but I can't get the solution.

I have asked the same [question on Magento Stack](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/typeerror-image-elevatezoom-is-not-a-function-bug-in-magento-1-9-rwd-theme).

Comment: file path is design/frontend/rwd/default/template/review/product/view/list.phtml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've got the same issue - not that it's a complete solution but it certainly stops the error for now, by stopping the function being called on the review page.

in the file /skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js

line 649 change

```
image.elevateZoom();
```

to

```
if ($('.review-product-list').length == 0) {
image.elevateZoom();
}
```

Comment: glad to be of assistance.

Comment: will you please post the same answer on the actual question asked in magento stack at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/typeerror-image-elevatezoom-is-not-a-function-failure-in-magento-1-9-rwd-theme

Comment: I'd highly recommend to not edit app.js directly from inside the rwd/default theme. Instead, copy it to skin/frontend/rwd/YOUR_THEME/js/app.js (replace YOUR_THEME with your actual theme name). That way if you upgrade Magento your fix won't be undone. Unfortunately this app.js seems to throw a lot of errors, and despite several minor updates since 1.9 was release the core development team has done little to nothing to fix them

Comment: Good point, Meogi. I'd recommend doing this also - at the time of answering I was quite new to Magento and only knew of the fix due to having the same issue myself :)

Answer (score 2):

We just ran across this for a client. This was resolved by changing the script being referenced from the min version to the full version. So replace this:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type>   
  <script>js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.0.8.min.js</script>
</action>
```

With this:

```
<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type> 
  <script>js/lib/elevatezoom/jquery.elevateZoom-3.js</script>
</action>
```

The error resolved and zoom is working.

Comment: where did you change this?

Answer (score 1):

Open `app/design/frontend/your-package/your-theme/template/catalog/product/view/media.html` Comment below section of code

```
<!-- <script type="text/javascript">
    // <![CDATA[
        Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
            product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint');
        });
    //]]>
    </script> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and after a long search I use this code and every thing works well . I use `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` before `elevateZoom` function .

```
<script>
// Avoid PrototypeJS conflicts, assign jQuery to $j instead of $
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $("#zoom_07").elevateZoom({});

</script>
```